# How to add JSON values for the selected keys either using javascript or jquery or angularjs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, json

I have the following `json`:

```
var json = var data = [{
    "a": 150
}, {
    "a": 50
}, {
    "b": 100
}, {
    "b": 25
}];
```

I wanted to add the values of "`a`" and "`b`" in my `finaljson`(it's my desired output json), like:

```
var finaljson = [{
    "a": 200
}, {
    "b": 125
}];
```

How can I get the above `finaljson` resultant structure for the given `json` content either using `javascript` or `jquery` or `angularjs` ?

Please note that here the `finaljson` should be the adding of above "`a`" values and "`b`" values like: `a: 150+50=200, b: 100+25=125`.

Please let me know and Thanks in advance. Created [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Guna1/mhz1p13g/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a hash table as reference to the result for the same keys.

```js
var data = [{ "a": 150 }, { "a": 50 }, { "b": 100 }, { "b": 25 }],
    result = data.reduce(function (hash) {
        return function (r, a) {
            var key = Object.keys(a)[0],
                o = {};

            if (!hash[key]) {
                o[key] = 0;
                hash[key] = o;
                r.push(o);
            }
            hash[key][key] += a[key];
            return r;
        };
    }(Object.create(null)), []);

console.log(result);
```

ES6 with [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)

```js
var data = [{ "a": 150 }, { "a": 50 }, { "b": 100 }, { "b": 25 }],
    result = data.reduce((map => (r, a) => {
        var key = Object.keys(a)[0];
        if (!map.has(key)) {
            map.set(key, { [key]: 0 });
            r.push(map.get(key));
        }
        map.get(key)[key] += a[key];
        return r;
    })(new Map), []);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var json = [{
    "a": 150
}, {
    "a": 50
}, {
    "b": 100
}, {
    "b": 25
}];

 var finaljson = [];
 var a= json[0].a+json[1].a;
 var b= json[2].b+json[3].b;
 finaljson.push(a);
  finaljson.push(b);
  console.log(finaljson);
```

Comment: I bet the SO needs a general dynamic solution independent of array indexes

Comment: @Mahi, I need the solution like: {
    "a": 200
}, {
    "b": 125
} . Please let me know and thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1):

What about this solution?

```
const json = [
  { "a": 150 }, 
  { "a": 50  }, 
  { "b": 100 }, 
  { "b": 25  }
];

const reduce = (data) => 
  data.reduce((acc, obj) => {
    for(const i in obj){
      acc[i] = (acc[i] || 0) + obj[i];
    }
    return acc;
  }, {})
;

reduce(json);
```

Will output

```
{
    "a": 200,
    "b": 125
}
```

Comment: @Guna Sorry, there was anerror in the code. Please recheck. Now it works correctly.

Comment: => what is that mean ?

Comment: It's [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Comment: `const` is a reserved keyword, you can't name your variable `const`, and then naming the actual `const` ... wait for it ... `reduce`, when you use `Array.reduce` ?

Comment: @ЕвгенийБеляев, as I am not getting the solution like above from your code ! Can you please check once ! Thanks in advance !

Comment: @ЕвгенийБеляев, thanks for your reply, it's working fine !

Answer (score 1):

```
let json = [   
    { "a": 150 },
    { "a": 50  },
    { "b": 100 },
    { "b": 25  } 
];

let sumSameProperties = function (json) {
    let middleJson = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < json.length; ++i) {
        let keys = Object.keys(json[i]);
        for (let k = 0; k < keys.length; ++k) { 
            if(!isNaN(middleJson[keys[k]])){
                middleJson[keys[k]] += json[i][keys[k]];
            }else {
                middleJson[keys[k]] = json[i][keys[k]];
            }
        }
    }
    return middleJson;
};
let finalJson = [];
let almostThere = sumSameProperties(json);
for (let key in almostThere) {
    let obj = {};
    obj[key] = almostThere[key];
    finalJson.push(obj);
}
console.log(finalJson);
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, yes, it's working as per requirement too !